# xpages why is validation running when I load my xpage?

Tags: validation, xpages, onload

It hadn't been doing that. Nothing seems to be triggered when the page is loading. What would trigger SSJS validation to run upon opening an xpage?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Has a datasource on your XPage the *computeWithForm* propety set to *onload* or *both*?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to give an exact answer. I recommend watching the [XPages Master Class](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=xpages%20masterclass). It will explain the JSF life cycle and show you how to use the XPages toolbox to diagnose your application to get the answer.

Comment: Post the code to the entire XPAGE? That would be massive.
I appreciate the suggestion on going to watch the XPAGES MASTER CLASS, but all I am asking is why validation would run when the page is loading. I've been working on this for months, and it never ran before. There must be some basic properties about the XPage that would cause it to do this that can be suggested.

Comment: There is nothing in your current question that can give you an exact answer. You don't need the full page, but at least reduce to sample of the issue. The Masterclass videos explain when and where validation runs,  and how to diagnose your code to find why it is acting the way it is.

Comment: I can't understand what that guy is saying...neither the annunciation nor the content.
I tried posting the code here, but it said it was too long by 50,000 characters.

This is frustrating because this app is about ready to go into production except I can't get it to stop validating when loading.

I will likely scrap the entire xpages project I've been working on for months and just create this using a form instead unless I can find a simpler way to troubleshoot this one small issue.

Comment: Have you tried installing the XPages toolbox and following the instructions from that? (which is what the tutorial is about). You can at least see what your page is doing. http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/XPages%20Toolbox

Comment: Post the data source definition and a control with the validator which is being triggered. that would help understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check any partial refresh calls.  Use firebug to view network traffic
See if any Ajax calls are being made when page loads.  Also check 
If you have any converters altering data that might trigger the validation